# ArcScene: Export Multipatch to CAD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, cad, multipatch

I have a 3D multipatch feature class in a file geodatabase using ArcScene 10.4.1. I would like to export this 3D data to CAD using "Export to CAD (Conversion)".

The tools runs, but the resulting DWG-file is only 12kb and is empty.

Is it even possible to export 3D multipatch-files to CAD using ArcGIS?

Just exporting the 2D footprints to CAD is working.

The geometry is fine.

[image]

Comment: nobody who has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have had exactly the same problem - both in ArcScene and in ArcGIS Pro. I solved it by installing Data Interoperability Extension for ArcGIS Pro. I built a very simple tool reading a shape-file (multipatch featureclass from file geodatabase is not recognized) and writing to a dxf-file using format Esri Mapping Specification for CAD (MSC).